# Row's child making alignment based on their child size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

These two rows are aligned based on their child sizes.

That's why the first TAGS and second TAGS text widgets are not centered. I want them to be properly centered like CSS Grid.

My Approach:

```
Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: const [
                        Text("Name"),
                        Text("Tags"),
                        Text("Default"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: const [Text("USER OTP SENT"), Text("TAGS"), Text("SMS")],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
```

[image: Center Alignment]

I want them to align like this (Red Lines determine the starting/ending position):

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `Table()` ? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try flutter `DataTable`. It can organize data in table easily

You can see the `DataTable` documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is GridView Widget in Flutter just like in CSS.

1. Use GridView.count() then define crossAxisCount to specify the number of widgets on the horizontal axis (yours are 3).

2.Use **childAspectRatio (itemWidth / itemHeight)** to get the desired height.

3. In code 6 children were defined as mentioned 3 of them are going to be laid out in a row.

```html
GridView.count(
          primary: false,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.5,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 10,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text(
                "Name",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text(
                'Tags',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text(
                'Default',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('USER OTP SENT',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Tags', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('SMS', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

[Here you can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NL2w.png)

Answer (score 0):

To archive exact UI, you need to use another `Row` inside `Row`.

```dart
 Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        // color: Colors.black,
        height: 50,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              const Expanded(child: Text("Name")),
              Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: const [
                  Text("Tags"),
                  Text("Default"),
                ],
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
        height: 50,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Expanded(child: Text("USER OTP SENT")),
              Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: const [Text("TAGS"), Text("SMS")],
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**
I will suggest using `LayoutBuilder` and `SizedBox` to decorate,

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          // color: Colors.black,
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          height: 50,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width:
                      (constraints.maxWidth / 3) - (defaultPadding / 1.5),
                  child: const Text("Name"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width:
                      (constraints.maxWidth / 3) - (defaultPadding / 1.5),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Tags",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width:
                      (constraints.maxWidth / 3) - (defaultPadding / 1.5),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Default",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                ...const [
                  Text("USER OTP SENT"),
                  Text(
                    "TAGS",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "SMS",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),
                ].map((e) => SizedBox(
                      width: (constraints.maxWidth / 3) -
                          (defaultPadding / 1.5),
                      child: e,
                    ))
              ].toList(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

**Solution 3:** Or use `Expanded` with `textAlign`

```dart
SizedBox(
    height: 50,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          // color: Colors.black,
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Expanded(child: Text("Name")),
                Expanded(
                    child:
                        Text("Tags", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Default",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: const Color(0xFF5D5C5D),
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Expanded(child: Text("USER OTP SENT")),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("TAGS", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "SMS",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ))
```

[image]